# How to handle the error message without getting the error in Jenkins result

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

The below code is throwing ‘stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document’

How to handle  error message and show the result as a pass

Action- The below code is adding one image(which can be one or more) which inside another image

```
public void click_on_the_Add_to_collection_button_displaying_down_below_the_assert()  {



    List<WebElement> all_colection = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li//button[@class='icon-button ' and @title='Add To Collection']"));

    int collection_size = all_colection.size();

    System.out.println("the collection size is " + collection_size);

    Random ran = new Random();

    

    all_colection.get(collection_size - 1).click();


    crate_new_colection.sendKeys("newcollection#1");


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap with `try..catch` like shown below:

```java
public void click_on_the_Add_to_collection_button_displaying_down_below_the_assert()  {
    try{
        List<WebElement> all_colection = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li//button[@class='icon-button ' and @title='Add To Collection']"));
        int collection_size = all_colection.size();
        System.out.println("the collection size is " + collection_size);
        Random ran = new Random();
        all_colection.get(collection_size - 1).click();
        crate_new_colection.sendKeys("newcollection#1");
    }catch (StaleElementReferenceException e){
        System.err.println("Skipping the exception. Do not let it get down stack.");
    }
}
```

**P.S.** - I kept your [snake case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) unchanged but please do not use Python-like code style in Java.